# Want to rewrite the query as follows to display data

Tags: mysql

I have a result table like this

| UniqueID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 98 |
| 1 | 99 |
| 2 | 100 |
| 2 | 98 |
| 3 | 99 |

and I want to display the result as follows using SQL

| UnqiueID | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 98 | 99 |
| 2 | 100 | 98 |  |
| 3 | 99 |  |  |

Please suggest queries using single table and multiple tables

Comment: [Pivot questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D+and+%28%5Bpivot%5D+or+%5Bcrosstab%5D%29)

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Please don't Write With random Capital Letters like This because it Makes reading Your Question very Annoying.

Comment: Your 'UniqueID' is not unique